# How can I autowire static fields in spring without Sonarqube issue?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, sonarqube, autowired

I know from this solution I can autowired static fields in spring.

```
@Component
public class AdminUtil {

    private static IAirportService airportService;

    @Autowired
    public AdminUtil(IAirportService portService) {
        AdminUtil.airportService = portService;
    }

    ...

 }
```

But sonar says: **Static fields should not be updated in constructors** ([RSPEC-3010](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3010))

Is there any alternate way to autowired static fields in spring? Or do I ignore this?

Comment: **Don't**. Why would you even do this? Sorry to say, but this shows a fundamental misunderstanding of Inversion of Control and even what `static` means. Heed SonarQube's warning - don't do this.

Comment: What possible purpose could this serve?

Comment: @BoristheSpider in this util file contains some converter, calculate etc. methods. I needed to use it in a method.

Comment: But you cannot until you have an instance - that's what the Sonar warning means. This, to all intents and purposes, makes it non static. The thing you have created is a Spring Bean - hence the autowiring happening. So **inject** the bean where you need it. Using static methods breaks IoC and defeats the very purpose of it - greater decoupling and therefore greater testability.

Answer (score -1):

Spring's idea is that `Component`s get instantiated once by default and reused throughout the application. This should be save as long as the components don't hold state.
Considering your code sample the easiest solution would be to not make the `airportService` static.

Comment: Whilst the first comment is true, it's not relevant. For example Spring does clever things with establishing the dependencies of beans to work out what order to create them in - this breaks that; your application may randomly throw NPEs.